# Create two different timer jobs but SharePoint keeps assigning the same name

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, custom-timer-job

I have a SharePoint 2013 project with two very different custom timer jobs in it. In the feature I create the jobs with two different name, but when going to "Job Definitions" in Central Admin, I can see the two jobs but they have the same name. it will use the name assigned to the first job for both, so I can switch them around in code and still get the same effect, my feature code is below:

```
const string JobName = "Client Portal Update";
const string NewClientJobName = "New Client Prep";

private bool CreateJob(SPWebApplication site)
{
    bool jobCreated = false;

     try
     {
          ClientUpdateTimerJob job = new ClientUpdateTimerJob(JobName, site);

          SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
          schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
          schedule.EndSecond = 59;
          schedule.Interval = 15;
          job.Schedule = schedule;

          job.Update();

          NewClientPrepTimerJob newClientJob = new NewClientPrepTimerJob(NewClientJobName, site);
          SPMinuteSchedule newClientSchedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
          newClientSchedule.BeginSecond = 0;
          newClientSchedule.EndSecond = 59;
          newClientSchedule.Interval = 30;
          newClientJob.Schedule = newClientSchedule;

          newClientJob.Update();
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          jobCreated = false;
      }

      return jobCreated;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to split them in 2 features, i.e. 2 event receivers?

Comment: Does your timer job implement the usage of the name that you pass as a parameter or is the name Hard-coded into the TimerJob class? - The Name that is used is a Property of the SPJobDefinition class

Comment: Post the constructor code of class `ClientUpdateTimerJob` and `NewClientPrepTimerJob`